# How to remove small regions connected by a few pixels from the main region of a binary image?

Tags: image, matlab, edge-detection, image-morphology, binary-image

I have the following image which I have obtained after a segmentation process.

[image]

Which function or algorithm should I use to remove the small regions (marked by red circles) that are connected to the main segmented region by a very small number of pixels? I know of `bwareaopen`, but that can only be used to remove regions that are not connected at all.

Comment: Could you also add the original picture? So people can perform tests on it?

Comment: Sure. Here it is.    <https://i.imgur.com/VIsKNOG.jpg>

Answer (score 0):

```
im = imread('image.jpg');
BW=rgb2gray(im);
BW=imbinarize(BW);
se = strel('disk',7);
imshow(bwmorph(imclose(BW,se),'thin',10));
```

This code produces closest result
[image]

After that you can appy different morphological process to get rid of undesired lines.